# Servers can't find each other

Tags: linux, nginx, curl

I had originally posted this on Superuser, but for some reason it got marked off-topic, so this seems like the only reasonable place left to post this.

I have a web server, which hosts my website (https://thijs365.com/) and my Nextcloud server (https://cloud.thijs365.com). That Nextcloud server is configured to use a OnlyOffice document server (https://docservice.thijs365.com/). However, the Nextcloud install can't reach the document server. After some digging around, I found that I also wasn't able to `curl -L` my website; it just times out. Nginx is configured to proxy-pass to the document server. I have split up my config into multiple files; you can find my config for thijs365.com [here](https://pastebin.com/vrJHCsBy), the docservice config can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/7yDWarND), the ssl config [here](https://pastebin.com/A0u8eiTS), the nextcloud config [here](https://pastebin.com/PXwgUask), and the php config [here](https://pastebin.com/5tZg6SRT). My web server runs Ubuntu 18.04, and my document server runs CentOS 7.

**Update:**
I have found that `curl`ing from my laptop **does** work, which means that the servers can't reach each other internally.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by giving the document server a certificate. I then added the internal IP, followed by the hostname in the /etc/hosts file. This worked. It's quite sketchy, but with problems like this you don't have much choice.